# Best package for SVN (Subversion)

Tags: svn

Emacs 26.1.

To work with Git I use package **magit**. It's very nice package.

But I also need package to work with SVN. Has analog of magit but to work with SVN ?

Answer (score 2):

SVN is supported by Emacs' built-in [version control system](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html).

I don't think there's anything comparable to magit for SVN, partly because git is much more capable than SVN, and partly because fewer and fewer people have been using SVN since git came along.

Answer (score 2):

The Foundation I work for also uses Subversion exclusively, since quite a few features they need would not be handled as easily using git (some of them: huge monorepos, centralised workflow, excellent TortoiseSvn client).

Some of the engineers use [dsvn](https://github.com/emacsmirror/dsvn).  Some use [psvn](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsPSVN.html). I personally use the built in Emacs VC system.

See also [Subversion on EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=SubVersion;id=Subversion).